# How to get access to the firebase Authentication part

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

In my app I've 2 login methods(google&facebook) and all the users appear in the Authentication part inside my firebase project, and I haven't list/collection of my users in my database.

I want to display in my app list of users with some personal data.

My question is how do i get access to the users from the Authentication part(to get all the users for example)?

Is it good approach that the users appear only in the Authentication and not inside my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't list user accounts with the Firebase Authentication client SDK.  You can only do that with the Firebase Admin SDK on a backend you control.

If you think it's OK for your users to be able to know all other users, then you should store that information in your database to make it queryable directly from the client, or create some sort of API endpoint where you can invoke the Admin SDK from your app.