# How to fetch all registered authentication emails in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to query firebase and return a list of all authentication emails registered?
I would like to send emails to all the emails in the database using android studio.
Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39757121, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38168973, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56566791

Answer (score 0):

Client apps are not allowed to get lists of users directly from Firebase Authentication - there is not even an API for that.  You will have to build something on your own.

One approach is to have each user write their information to a database that can be queried by other users.

Another approach is to have the client call a backend that uses the Firebase Admin SDK to list users and return that to the client.